# Drag copy value if cell contains "text" until next cell containing "text"

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I'm trying to create a Macro to sort customer data which is organized with a header ("CUSTOMER:ABC") in column A followed by rows of data about that customer and finally a total header in column A ("TOTAL") with total data along that row. This is repeated for the whole list of customers. What I want to do is create a Macro that simulates drag copying the customer name down to (and including) the cell with total header. I don't need to move any of the data, just need to fill all of column A with customer names.

Ex.
1. CUSTOMER: ABC
2.
3.
4. TOTAL
5. CUSTOMER: XYZ
6.
7. TOTAL
Change to:
1. CUSTOMER: ABC
2. CUSTOMER: ABC
3. CUSTOMER: ABC
4. CUSTOMER: ABC
5. CUSTOMER: XYZ
6. CUSTOMER: XYZ
7. CUSTOMER: XYZ

Comment: do you have empty cells in between?

Comment: Yes, there are spaces in between. The "CUSTOMER" entries in Column A are like titles with a mix of blank cells and dates until the next "CUSTOMER" header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub mySub()
   Dim nRows As Integer: nRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim cell As Range, r As Range: Set r = Range("A2:A" & nRows)
   For Each cell In r
        If InStr(1, LCase(cell.Value), "customer:") < 1 Then cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1).Value
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! The macro seems to be replacing the entire Column A with empty cells. Is this something to do with what you mentioned about blank cells?

Comment: Upon further testing the macro seems to be copying down whatever is in A1 for all of column A

Comment: Are the numbers 1. 2. 3. etc actually present in the worksheet's cells, or they are here just for illustration?

Comment: That was because of case-sensitivity and because the keyword customer: might not be at the beginning of the cell. I changed the code so that it is not case-sensitive and can capture the keyword at any place. plz try the edited version.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank-you so much A.S.H